# Can I use another open workbook's VBA Functions in another open workbook within a Cell formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some VBA functions defined within my Personal.xlsb that I want to use in the Cell formulae for other opened workbooks. I can use these functions within Cell formulae within worksheets in Personal.xlsb, however I can't seem to use these within other opened workbooks... I get the #NAME errors whinging that it can't find the function name.

I hope I've just done something stupid..

FYI for example, one function accepts some arguments including a Cell, and returns an element from the cell's value at a particular position (say Cell.Value = This.Is.An.Example, the function might return "An") effectively replicating a split()[2]

Cheers

Comment: Where in your Personal.xlsb have you placed the functions? How have you declared them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference functions in the Personal.xlsb with the filename, like this:

```
=PERSONAL.XLSB!myFunctionName(A1)
```

If you don't want to do that for each function, you can create a reference in your new workbook's VBE. Go Tools > References and find the workbook in the list.

See a walkthrough of the whole process here: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/creating-a-reference-to-personal-xlsb-for-user-defined-functions-udfs

Comment: I also found in that article at the bottom how to (super easily) create the personal workbook as an Add-In instead which now gives me access to Excel's basic IntelliSense for my custom functions :) and avoids the workbook reference

Comment: Yes, that article, and all of that site, is a great resource.